# What is the latest that we know about odd perfect numbers?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

What is the latest that we know about odd perfect numbers?

I have seen some recent papers by [Nielsen](http://math.byu.edu/~pace/BestBound_web.pdf), and [Ochem & Rao](http://www.lirmm.fr/~ochem/opn/opn_radical_rev.pdf).  I was wondering if there are any others.

Comment: recents posts are http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179504/a-problem-concerning-odd-perfect-number, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178286/is-there-an-odd-integer-x-105-for-which-it-is-known-that-x-nmid-n-if-n, but you might know this already.

Comment: @grin@, I made the second post @DietrichBurde.